# How can a critical Adobe Acrobat security update, only available as an unsigned executable over plain HTTP, be verified?

Tags: macos, updates

A [critical security update for Adobe Acrobat Pro and Standard 9](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4374&fileID=4081) on Mac OSX is only available over HTTP, and is unsigned code. Is there any out-of-band way to verify the download is authentically from Adobe?

Answer (score 3):

You're right. If you go to Adobe's website the update is transferred over HTTP and not HTTPS, which give any hacker in the network to hijack your update file with a simple [Man In The Middle Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and inject his/her malicious file instead of the legitimate Adobe's update.

However if you go to the same page and instead of clicking the *download now* button you copy the link and add **HTTPS** as a prefix to it. The file will transferred securely over HTTPS.

here is the direct link: https://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/11.x/11.0.06/misc/AdbeRdrUpd11006.dmg

Comment: Alas, that site gives a browser warning, because it doesn't have an Adobe certificate - it has Akamai. That's better, perhaps I can trust the Adobe-Akamai relationship, but still a bit weak. I'm somewhat concerned because I've downloaded the update and done a Google search for its MD5 and SHA1 hex values - and there are no mentions of those strings anywhere.